# Is the matrix multiplication algorithm for NxM and MxP matrices O(NP) in space?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, big-o, space-complexity

When multiplying two matrices, we need to allocate a third one to store the result. Should this allocation be considered when calculating the memory consumption of the algorithm?

Comment: Also, the answer to this question is: it's purely a matter of how you choose your definition of memory complexity.

Comment: Oli is correct +1 - your assumptions/definitions define the scope of possible answers.  I think subjective is a better way to phrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine an argument that the space required for an algorithm is less than what is required to store the result; that should be the lower bound of the space required.

But apparently my imagination is not up to the task at hand, and neither the space for the input parameters nor the space for the output/result should be counted against the algorithm.

So (as the comments below have convinced me): no.

Comment: This is entirely subjective.  You could equally argue that the fundamental cost of storing the result is nothing to do with the algorithm, and therefore shouldn't be attributed to it.

Comment: If the goal of the algorithm is the computation of that value, and you DON'T have to store it, couldn't that be implemented with one big no-op?  Seems to dramatically alter what "cost" means.  Could you give an example where the cost of representing the result isn't consider part of the space complexity of an algorithm, as I honestly can't think of one.

Comment: What I mean is, for a given task (matrix multiply in this case), it doesn't matter which algorithm you choose, there's always an inherent cost of needing to store the output somewhere.  But that cost is associated with the task, not the algorithm.

Comment: I'm a simple guy: the algorithm needs the space, so it counts toward its complexity.  Suppose we had an algorithm for a slightly different problem: the sum of the elements of this matrix product.  That has a DRAMATICALLY different space requirement, but by your argument (as best I can follow it), the two would have no difference in space complexity.

Comment: The allocation of the result space can be done outside of the algorithm itself. If the result is returned by reference, is the algorithm now magically O(1)? That's what troubles me with the question.

Comment: @ScottHunter: Yes, I would indeed say that they had the same spatial complexity (assuming neither of them need no other storage).  Consider that the result storage could be provided from some external source...

Comment: Does it matter who allocates it?  If the space isn't there, the algorithm can't be executed; that's why an algorithm that needs the space has a higher complexity than one that doesn't.

Comment: @ScottHunter: By your argument, an in-place algorithm always has at least O(n) spatial complexity.  So in fact, there'd be no such thing as an algorithm with e.g. O(1) complexity.

Comment: @Oli: Addition of 2 integers would have O(1) spatial complexity.

Comment: @ScottHunter: That doesn't really make any sense, though, because you can't talk about asymptotic complexity when your problem size is fixed.

Comment: @Oli: OK, so if your problem size can't be a constant, and thus the space to STORE the inputs can't be constant, then I guess you shouldn't have any O(1) space complexity algorithms.

Comment: Which is what leads me to believe it's not a very useful definition (and is not one that is typically used in practice - see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms).

Comment: Is there any work done in Kolmogorov complexity that could formally prove that the solution space could not possibly occupy less than what the result is?

Answer (score 0):

As other responses say, you must differentiate between the space taken by the matrix itself and the multiplication algorithm.

As for a classic NxM matriz data structure, the space taken is O(NM).

As for the algorithm per se, it depends:
the basic secuential multiplication algorithm takes O(1) space since it multiply and sum one element at a time.

In a parallel algorithm multiplying NxM and MxP matrixes, each processor should take O(1) space since each process calculates one multiplcation value, but is O(X) in space, where X is the number of parallel processes working on the solution.